# How to create a ASPX file after clicking a button on another form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Hopefully this is clear enough, i have this bit of code :

```
        private void BtnAdd_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Demo\Demo\" + BtnName.Value;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
        }
```

That creates a folder named after the value of a text box, and i need to know if there's a way to create an aspx file the same way, and save it in one of those folders or anywhere it just needs to be accessible to the project, thanks in advance! I'm open to any questions or code updates.

Comment: If the given code works then wouldn't setting BtnName.Value to "Foo.aspx" accomplish the task?

Comment: The code works, but i get a syntax error message, I believe there's a library to do that, i was looking and i couldn't find anything.

Comment: There's a whole namespace, `System.IO` that contains everything you need to work with folders and files. For example, to create a file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.8. My question is, what do you mean by "it just needs to be accessible to the project"?

Comment: Also, providing what the syntax error says will also be helpful.

Comment: BY accessible i mean that the project can look it up and open it, but thanks for the link, lets see if i can get this done!