# How to modify an ASPX file from another one

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a .aspx page (an editor), on this page you can place buttons and those buttons need to appear in the Default.aspx, i did some research and i only got a piece of code that can help you create dynamically another .aspx page (with content), but what i need is a way to save those buttons created in the editor to the main page (Default.aspx).

This is the piece of code that i found :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

private void BtnAdd_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath = path.ToString() + BtnName.Value + ".aspx";
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(FilePath))
        {
            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Content");
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(FilePath))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The expected output needs to be a custom button created from a aspx and this button needs to be in lets say a `<div>`, if this question is not clear enough please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Hello, again. Obviously, this question continues from where your previous question left off: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962653/how-to-create-a-aspx-file-after-clicking-a-button-on-another-form ...

Comment: Hey!, the previous question was about creating a form from a button, this one is to add elements to them after being created or already existing ones, i don't know if something from the previous question will help me, if so, please let me know, thanks again!